# Get coordinates from a wikipedia page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping this page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_Tower_Place

And I need the coordinates that appear there, latitude and longitude

I try with:

```
scrapy shell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_Tower_Place


response.xpath('//*[@id="coordinates"]/span/span/a/span[1]/span/span[1]')
```

but get an empty list as response

I can get it using regex

```
re.findall('latitude([^<]+)',str(response.body))
```

but it has special characters, but I guess there's a simple way to get the number directly without dealing with special characters

```
['">41\xc2\xb053\xe2\x80\xb252.5\xe2\x80\xb3N']]
```

Edit:

My bad, when I print it I get the latitude,

41°53′52.5″N

either way, I would be interesting to know how to get the value without regex

Comment: @BobDylan I see it at the top right, below the search bar

Comment: `/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/p[22]/span/span/span/a/span[1]/span/span[1]` is full xpath, I see it now

Comment: It works but I need a more general expression, that doesn't work at this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lafayette_Square_Mal. How did you get it? I use chrome to get the xpath.

Comment: Have you tried using DBpedia as a go-between? http://dbpedia.org/page/Water_Tower_Place lists `lat` and `long` as fields, and you can get that data directly as JSON or XML.

Comment: Maybe requesting JSON data through the [wikidata API](https://wikidata.org) works better than parsing the HTML rendering

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at those options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use xpath, you can use:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="latitude"]/text()').extract()[0]
```

and:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="longitude"]/text()').extract()[0]
```

Comment: FYI, `extract_first()` can be used instead of `extract()[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would rely on the specific `latitude` and `longitude` classes:

```
$ scrapy shell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_Tower_Place
>>> print response.css(".geo-dms .latitude::text").extract_first()
41°53′52.5″N
>>> print response.css(".geo-dms .longitude::text").extract_first()
87°37′20.5″W
```

Comment: How do ypu get the path? with chorme I get: #coordinates > span > span > a > span.geo-default > span > span.latitude

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez there are so many ways to get to these elements. I really like the `latitude` and `longitude` classes - they are making the locators quite readable. The `coordinates` id sounds good too. So, here is an another way: `#coordinates .latitude::text` and `#coordinates .longitude::text` - quite readable and efficient.